# How can i remove selected parent nodes from treeview in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I copied and paste a code form other form which contains a treeview given below

1.Masters

- tree
- plant

2.Transaction

- leaf
- seed

3.Report

- root

4.Utilities

- bird

for my form i need only report, transaction and its child nodes I need to remove Report,Utilities and and its child nodes

1.Master

- tree
- Plant

2.Transaction

- leaf
- seed

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["Name"] == null)
   {
       Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
   }
   else
   {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
           DataTable dt2 = GetData(0);
           PopulateTreview(dt2, 0, null);
       }
   }
}

private DataTable GetData(int parentMenuId)
{
   string query = "SELECT [MenuId], [Title] FROM [Menus] WHERE ParentMenuId = @parentMenuId Order by GroupCode,Title";
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
   {
       using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
       {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentMenuId", parentMenuId);
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
           sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
           sda.Fill(dt);
       }
   }
   return dt;
}

private void PopulateTreview(DataTable dt3, int ParentMenuId, TreeNode ParentTreenode)
{
   string cType = "";
   int nParentId = 0;
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt3.Rows)
   {
       TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
       node.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
       node.Value = dr["MenuId"].ToString();


       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Menus where MenuId=" + node.Value;
       cmd.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
       using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           if (sdr.Read())
           {
               cType = sdr["Type"].ToString();
               nParentId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ParentMenuId"]);
           }
       }

       if (cType == "T")
       {
           if (ParentMenuId == 0)
           {
               TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
               DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(node.Value));
               PopulateTreview(dtChild, int.Parse(node.Value), node);
           }
           else
           {
               ParentTreenode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
           }
           TreeNode cAdd = new TreeNode("Add");
           TreeNode cEdit = new TreeNode("Edit");
           TreeNode cDelete = new TreeNode("Delete");

           TreeNode pn = TreeView1.SelectedNode ?? TreeView1.Nodes[0];
           if (pn != null && nParentId != 0)
           {
               node.ChildNodes.Add(cAdd);
               node.ChildNodes.Add(cEdit);
               node.ChildNodes.Add(cDelete);
               TreeView1.ExpandAll();
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (ParentMenuId == 0)
           {
               TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
               DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(node.Value));
               PopulateTreview(dtChild, int.Parse(node.Value), node);
           }
           else
           {
               ParentTreenode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
           }
       }
   }
}

private void GetCheckMenus(TreeNode treeNode)
{
   cTitle = "";
   string cType = "";
   int nNum;
   bool isNum = int.TryParse(treeNode.Value.ToString(), out nNum);
   if (isNum)
   {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Menus Where MenuId='" + treeNode.Value + "'";
       cmd.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
       using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           if (sdr.Read())
           {
               cTitle = sdr["Title"].ToString();
               cType = sdr["Type"].ToString();
           }
       }
   }
   if (cTitle != "")
   {
       if (treeNode.Checked == true)
       {
           if (cType == "T")
           {
               SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert_UserOpt", Global.DriverCon);
               cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", txtUId.Text.Trim());
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Menu", cTitle);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", 1);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("MenuId", treeNode.Value);
               foreach (TreeNode cn in treeNode.ChildNodes)
               {
                   GetChild(cn);
               }
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADD", nChildVal.Substring(0, 1));
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDIT", nChildVal.Substring(1, 1));
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELETE", nChildVal.Substring(2, 1));

               cmd1.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
               cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               nChildVal = "";
           }
           else
           {
               SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert_UserOpt", Global.DriverCon);
               cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", txtUId.Text.Trim());
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Menu", cTitle);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", 1);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("MenuId", treeNode.Value);
               foreach (TreeNode cn in treeNode.ChildNodes)
               {
                   GetChild(cn);
               }
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADD", "");
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDIT", "");
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELETE", "");

               cmd1.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
               cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               nChildVal = "";
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (cType == "T")
           {
               SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert_UserOpt", Global.DriverCon);
               cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", txtUId.Text.Trim());
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Menu", cTitle);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", 0);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("MenuId", treeNode.Value);
               foreach (TreeNode cn in treeNode.ChildNodes)
               {
                   GetChild(cn);
               }
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADD", nChildVal.Substring(0, 1));
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDIT", nChildVal.Substring(1, 1));
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELETE", nChildVal.Substring(2, 1));

               cmd1.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
               cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               nChildVal = "";
           }
           else
           {
               SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert_UserOpt", Global.DriverCon);
               cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               //cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserId", txtUId.Text.Trim());
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Menu", cTitle);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", 0);
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("MenuId", treeNode.Value);
               foreach (TreeNode cn in treeNode.ChildNodes)
               {
                   GetChild(cn);
               }
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADD", "");
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EDIT", "");
               cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DELETE", "");

               cmd1.Connection = Global.DriverCon;
               cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               nChildVal = "";
           }
       }
   }

   foreach (TreeNode tn in treeNode.ChildNodes)
   {
       GetCheckMenus(tn);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried the method below but its showing Exception user unhandled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing them, don't load them in the first place. Add a filter in `GetData`:

```sql
SELECT [MenuId], [Title]
FROM [Menus]
WHERE ParentMenuId = @parentMenuId AND MenuId NOT IN (1, 2)
Order by GroupCode, Title
```

I added `AND MenuId NOT IN (1, 2)` to the existing query. Replace `(1, 2)` by a list of the unwanted MenuIds of top-level tree items.

Comment: The exception might contain a more explicit inner exception. We need to know the cause of the exception before fixing it. You could also try to execute this query in the SQL Server Management Studio to see whether it works. (I also removed `";` at the end of the query, which was a left over from the C# code.)